# Swift ivars: set all constants in initializer, or have clean initializer and give up constant?

Tags: ios, swift

So this is a very simple question: say I have a view class. It has a bunch of properties: color, background color, font, image, etc. I don't expect any of those to change after the view is in place. In other words, it seems that they should be constants.

However, this seems to mean that I will need a very long initializer, something like

```
init(color: UIColor, backgroundColor: UIColor, font: UIFont, image: UIImage, frame: CGRect, ...)
```

which may go wild if I have more complicated classes with more should-be constant properties.

In Objective-C what I used to do is to `initWithFrame`, for example, and then set all the custom properties immediately afterwards. This does not seem to be possible with `let` in swift. Of course I can still use `var`, either `@lazy`-ly or making it optional, so I can have a reasonable initializer.

So my question is, which approach is better, or is there a nicer alternative? I'd rather have my code **look** nice as well as work nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any time you can have the compiler assert something for you, that is a good thing. If you don't want a "wild" initializer, you can use a combination of [default parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_218) and [convenience initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_285).

Default parameters allow you to have a clean initializer without requiring a verbose call to init if you are happy with most of the defaults:

```
class MyClass {
    let att1 : String
    let att2 : Int
    let att3 : Int
    let att4 : Int
    let att5 : Int

    init(
        att1: String = "Hello",
        att2: Int = 2,
        att3: Int = 3,
        att4: Int = 4,
        att5: Int = 5
        )
    {
        self.att1 = att1
        self.att2 = att2
        self.att3 = att3
        self.att4 = att4
        self.att5 = att5
    }
}

MyClass(att1: "World")
MyClass(att4: 19, att3: 20)
MyClass(
    att1: "Hello",
    att2: 5,
    att3: 6,
    att4: 7,
    att5: 8
)
```

Otherwise, there is no way in Swift to have the compiler ensure a variable is only set once outside of an initializer. Your only option then is to use a runtime assert in a `willSet`:

```
class MyClass {
    var onlyOnce : String! {
        willSet {
            assert(!onlyOnce)
        }
    }
}

var foo = MyClass()
foo.onlyOnce = "Hello"
foo.onlyOnce = "World" // runtime error
```

Comment: If I set default value, then I cannot use `let` because then there's no way to set it to another value. That'd be a pure constant, not some set-and-stay-constant constant.

Comment: @Danqing isn't that exactly what you want? Or you're saying that you want to have a variable that can only be set 1 time? `let` properties can be changed / set in the initializer

Comment: Right, say I have a `color` property for some class. I want to set it once, and it won't be changed after that. If I have 10 such properties, do I need to set all of them in the initializer? That will blow up the initializer (into something super long).

Comment: @Danqing There is no way you can get the compiler to complain about assigning a variable more than once other than through initializers.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear, but my whole point is whether it's possible to avoid setting all the constants in the initializer, because in case there are 10+ should-be constants, the initializer would be very cumbersome.

Comment: @Danqing I thought the goal was to not require the user to define a whole bunch of attributes they didn't care about in the initializer. What is the difference between setting them in the initializer and setting the immediately after initializing? If you define defaults, they only have to specify the ones they want to not be default.

Comment: Right... I think setting default and dumping all properties in the initializer and then only setting the ones that need overriding seems to be the only way out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an amazingly cool Swift feature: you can leave a property without a default as a way of *forcing* that property to be set at initialization time. Do not defeat that cool feature!

Of course there are situations where you have to defeat it, like when you know that a real value will not be ready at initialization time — that, for example, is what `@IBOutlet` is all about. But in that case, what you should do is declare as an implicitly unwrapped optional, e.g.

```
var att1 : String!
```

The advantage of this is that if you try to get `att1` before setting it, you will crash, which is just what you (should) *want* to do.

In other words, you want to *force* yourself to initialize everything that can/should be initialized. Swift is here to help you do that, in a way that Objective-C cannot possibly do. Be happy and grateful and take advantage of Swift's offer of assistance!

As for your objection that the initializer will be long, that's just silly. With code completion, filling out a long initializer at the call site is no trouble at all. Still, I have one more suggestion: to make your initializer shorter, divide your attributes into small groups and create structs expressing them. I did that recently, using calculated properties to access the structs. Since what you want are constants, what you want to do is very similar to what I did:

```
class MyClass {
    let g : Grid // a lightweight struct I created for this purpose
    var x {
    return g.x // read-only!
    }
    var y {
    return g.y // read-only!
    }
    //...
}
```

And so later at the call site, I make a Grid (which has a short initializer) and then make a MyClass and pass the Grid to it, so that MyClass has a short initializer because it takes a few structs like Grid instead of all the attributes in series.

Comment: I think your suggestion about using structs to group members together is a good one to consider. But, using implicitly unwrapped optionals to require a user set properties is a pretty bad idea. To bring down an entire program because someone didn't set a variable they didn't realize they had to is excessive. It also doesn't prevent the user of an API from setting that variable more than once. It is FAR better to have reasonable defaults and if you really can't respond to the members changing, then they should be constants and be parameters to the initializer.

Comment: @drewag Not everything can be initialized at initialization time. That's just how life works.

Comment: agreed, in that case either provide a default value or use an optional